# Views in Databricks become broken after change of data type of a column in the source table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, ddl

I noticed that when data type of a column in delta table is changed from complex type to scalar type, all underlying views become broken.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

spark.sql("create table test.t1(col1 struct<member0: int, member1: string>)")
spark.sql("insert into test.t1 select struct(1, 'some text')")
spark.sql("create view test.v1 as select * from test.t1")
spark.sql("select * from test.v1") # <- works fine
# changing column data type to string
spark.read.table("test.t1").withColumn("col1", col("col1").cast("string")).write.mode("overwrite").option("overwriteSchema", "true").saveAsTable("test.t1")
spark.sql("select * from test.v1") # <- fails with an error
```

The error is: [CANNOT_UP_CAST_DATATYPE] Cannot up cast spark_catalog.test.t1.col1 from "STRING" to "STRUCT<member0: INT, member1: STRING>".

What to do in such cases? My goal is to be able to change columns data type when needed without breaking underlying views.
For now I see only option with drop+recreate the view.

Databricks version is 13.2, Spark is 3.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Views have columns and types just like tables and you can't just replace types without recreating view (because you need to redefine metadata of that view). I think that is more or less the case in relational databases as well.